# Enumerate and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, tikz-trees

How do I get my picture to start at the first line of an item instead of at the bottom?

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
    \item \{C\}$^{+}$ = ACD $\Leftarrow$ R is not BCNF.
    \medskip

    \item
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=15em]
    \node {R(ABCD)}
        child { node {R$_{1}$ = ABC} }
        child { node {R$_{2}$ = DBC} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add baseline = (current bounding box.north)

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
    \item \{C\}$^{+}$ = ACD $\Leftarrow$ R is not BCNF.
    \medskip

    \item
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=15em, baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
    \node {R(ABCD)}
        child { node {R$_{1}$ = ABC} }
        child { node {R$_{2}$ = DBC} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Maybe giving the first node a name and using `baseline=(firstnode.base)` would look even better.